# How to make straight wetting angle between water and glass

Tags: fluid-statics, laser, wetting

Looking for any liquid (preferably non hazard and transparent) which is immiscible with water in order to make a 90 degrees wetting angle with glass. Water+liquid should from a 90 degrees wetting angle on a glass surface. Colour doesn’t matter since can always add some ink to the water to make the edge clear.

Looked up and found that some oils such as silicone or mineral might work, but couldn’t really find clear images.

Also asked my senior who is PhD, she said there was some laser gun which she used to treat the glass before adding the water, but it was temporary solution. She already forgot the model and did not mention it in the paper, but she remembers that the laser was cheap.

Any help will be appreciated!